# How to run ASP.NET 4.0 website on Apache server?

Tags: asp.net, apache

I understood that I need to use «mod_aspdotnet», but I can't find this module for ASP.NET 4.0: only for 2.0.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to look at the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

They have a module for the Apache server called «mod_mono».

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the Nanohttpd library to create Web Server which runs on android. How can I host .asp file from it?

Comment: @AniketKapse please ask a new question about your topic, if you havent allready done so.

Answer (score 7):

Try the [Mod.Mono](http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono) instead of mod_aspdotnet:

This handles ASP.NET 4.0 (with the exception of Entity Framework).

See the [compatibility](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) for more information on what Mono is compatible with.

Comment: Yes, here is a page that documents everything that Mono is compatible with: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: are you sure? in the webpage http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET says it supports asp.net 2.0 .

Comment: @Pablo: Read the Compatibility link.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't want to use mod_aspdotnet.

You should be using mod_mono instead.

The Mono project is the authoritative project for running .NET code on non-Microsoft platforms. You can read up on it here:

[ASP.NET - Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)

And More specifically here:

[Mod mono - Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)