# Which programming languages can be deployed on Apache Server?

Tags: server, backend

I am a new back-end developer, I got a request that making a back-end can run on Apache server but I do not know what type of programming language can develop a back-end can run on that kind of server. I tried many queries about this topic but non result.Please help me!

I am planning to choose Golang for this project but I am confusing about it.

Comment: Lots and it depends. Typically Apache runs PHP. But (for example) there is nothing to [stop you running .Net on it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247383/how-to-run-asp-net-4-0-website-on-apache-server).

Comment: So the answer is everything, right?

Comment: Not quite everything, but anything that has an Apache runtime

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, [Apache's module page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/) doesn't list third party modules. However, there is a [Wikipedia page that lists third party modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache_modules).

- [mod_aspdotnet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/) - serves ASP.NET content using the Microsoft's ASP.NET hosting and .NET runtime
- [mod_cgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html) - executes CGI scripts
- [mod_cgid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgid.html) - executes CGI scripts using an external CGI daemon
- [mod_fcgid](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) - high performance alternative to mod_cgi or mod_cgid
- [mod_fastcgi](https://github.com/FastCGI-Archives/mod_fastcgi) - enables [FastCGI](http://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html)
- [mod_go](https://github.com/idaunis/mod_go) - module for deploying web applications in Go
- [mod_jk](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi) - handles the communication between Tomcat and Apache
- [mod_lisp](https://github.com/mbattyani/mod_lisp) - for writing web applications in lisp
- [mod_lua](http://www.sv.vt.edu/manual/tr/mod/mod_lua.html) - extends Apache with scripts written in Lua
- [mod_mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/) - provides ASP.NET support
- [mod_parrot](http://www.parrot.org/mod_parrot) - exposes the Apache API to a Parrot virtual machine interpreter
- [mod_perl](https://perl.apache.org/) - gives you a persistent Perl interpreter embedded in your web server
- mod_php - enables usage of PHP within Apache
- [mod_prolog](https://sourceforge.net/projects/modprolog/) - embeds the Prolog interpreter within the server
- [mod_python](http://modpython.org/) - embeds the Python interpreter within the server
- [mod_r](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/rapache/) - embeds the R interpreter inside Apache
- [mod_ruby](http://www.modruby.net/) - embeds a Ruby interpreter in Apache
- [mod_suphp](https://www.suphp.org/Home.html) - executes PHP scripts with the permissions of their owners (unmaintained)
- [mod_wsgi](https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/) - implements a WSGI compliant interface for hosting Python based web applications

It is likely that there are other modules that are unlisted because mod_go, mod_lua, and mod_prolog weren't included in the Wikipedia page. I found them by searching for "apache mod_golang", "apache mod_lua", and "apache mod_prolog". Also, a number of them no longer appear to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

We can say there are many languages which supports deployment on Apache web server. But here if you need a bunch of languages which runs natively on apache web server 
Then you can visit this site https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server
And explore features tab in it.
And you can see last 7 option in it which says

"Embedded Perl, PHP and Lua scripting"