# Apache on windows cant view asp.net files?

Tags: apache

I wonder if its just apache isnt suited well for windows but im kind of a noobie at this and everywhere i go i cant find a way to view asp.net files on my apache server. im running my server on my windows computer.

edit my computer can run asp.net files just fine, but when its in my server and opened through it, only the source appears for it.

edit2 my question is unique because Im using windows and i cant find instructions on how to install mod_mono on windows

Comment: Could you add details into your question, please? How and where did you install apache, did you install any asp handlers for it or did you do any configuration, where asp files are saved and where home directory of test domain you use (localhost?), etc. It will help others to answer your question faster and better.

Comment: the first question is (where did i install apache) is quite obvious actually. apache lounge. and idk what a asp handler is. i have my asp files saved in htdocs folder and i use my localhost as well as my sub domain ip and both dont work. @iXCray

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run ASP.NET 4.0 website on Apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247383/how-to-run-asp-net-4-0-website-on-apache-server)