# How to use Aspx page with Apache2 in linux server?

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache2

I have created one linux server. I installed Apache2, PHP, MySql-server and Phpmyadmin after moved all my files to the server. I cannot able to run some aspx files in my server. 
Can anyone please help me to install asp with apache2 in linux server.?

Comment: see this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247383/how-to-run-asp-net-4-0-website-on-apache-server

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Manusha. I've tried this, but no luck. Still the aspx code is displaying in frontend.